# Number formatting on badge requirements

Tags: bug

There are some instances that numbers are formatted with a comma, and some aren't. Using [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) as an example:

```
Famous Question    Asked a question with 10,000 views
Gold Badge         You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 
                   non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
Steward            Completed at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is 
                   awarded once per review type
Publicist          Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 
                   unique IP addresses
```

Can these be standardized/cleaned up?

Comment: Not a bug, that's how the team designed the page so changing it is a feature request.